# How to copy row data and put it into textbox with commas between rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am currently building a bulk email VBA device.  Everything is good to go, I just need to move the auto filtered data from the worksheet into the userform.

For Example if column B is the email list and there are 50 data points in a similar fashion...

```
EMAIL LIST
jsmith@gmail.com 
mschwitz@yahoo.com
email@gmail.com
etc...
```

Desired output in userform textbox: "jsmith@gmail.com, mschwitz@yahoo.com, email@gmail.com"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I just updated!

Comment: `join(application.transpose(yourRangeHere.value),",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [Tim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) code, add a button and use this, change the range to suit you. Make sure your button and textbox are correct.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim arr
    arr = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("B2:B51").Value), ",")
    Me.TextBox1 = arr
End Sub
```